# Spatially auto-regressive two-stage model

Tags: regression, data-mining, autocorrelation, spatial, autoregressive

I'm working on a project in which I use a 'Generalized Spatial Two-Stage Least Squares' model, mostly known as

$y= X \beta + \lambda W y + u$ and $u = \rho M u + \epsilon_n$

where $y$ and $u$ are vectors.

The beta's are the general regressionparameters (for instance, from linear regression). $W$ is a weight matrix, which could represent the inverse distance between each two instances, the same holds for $M$ (but not necessarily the same distance-meaning). $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are two parameters which has to be computed by iteration and have both an absolute value strictly smaller than 1. More information about this technique, can for example be found in [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sphet/vignettes/sphet.pdf) paper.

By making use of the program R I've already estimated the following variables

$\beta_0= -69900$ (intercept), $\beta_1=40630$, $\beta_2=-50$, $\lambda=0.8285$ and $\rho=-0.613$

My problem is that I don't know how to interpret this model as 'one model', ie as one equation. Another problem is that I have no idea how to use this model to make predictions by use of new input data.. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understande the model. How can $y_n$ can be present on the left and right part of the formula. What is $W$, $\lambda$, etc. Can you please explain it better?

Comment: I believe that the model is spatially auto-regressive, so the appearance of $y$ on RHS is a spatially-weighted mean of the *neighbors* of the observational element in $y$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a notational problem: the equation should be

$$
y = X\beta +\lambda W y+ u
$$
$$
u = \rho M u +\epsilon
$$
y,u must be vector otherwise the model does not make sense. The interpretation of the model depends on what you use as W and M, without this information seem difficult understand  the coefficient.

The model can be divided in three part:

1) the mean, that is $X\beta$, the interpretation is the same of the usual linear regression

2) the dependencies $\lambda W y$. This part tells you how to observations are correlated. Let suppose that $W$ is the inverse distance matrix,if $\lambda=0.9999$ means that if in a specific spatial point you observe a value $x$, in the neighborhood of  that spatial point you probably will observe a value close to x, if $\lambda=0$ what you observe in a spatial point tells you nothing on what happen on close spatial point.

3) the error term $\rho M u +\epsilon$ where i suppose the $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. In the models is generally assumed that the error are incorrelated and with the same variance. Here instead you assume that the error are correlated and the degree of correlation depends on the value of $\rho$, if $\rho=0$ you obtain incorrelated and homoschedastic error $u = \epsilon$, otherwise you have positive correlated error, $\rho>0$, or negative. The type of dependence between the error depend on what is $M$

Comment: Thats very helpful, thank you! The only thing I still don't get is how one can make predictions by use of new data (because I'm confused about the vector dimension of y and u in comparison with the ordinary linear regression technique, where the outcome is just a value)

Comment: With the autoregressive model is generally not possible to make prediction for a new set of unobserved points because the introduction of the new set o points should change the structure of W and M. Sometimes, it is possible to make prediction putting NA on the vector y where you want prediction during the model fitting. Suppose to have $n$ observation, in the linear regression you use $y_i, i =1,n$, here instead you use $y = (y_1, ..., y_n$. It is the same

Comment: So what is the general purpose of such a model? (I'm really new on this topic)

Comment: to estimate how strong is the dependence ($\lambda$) and if the error is structured in some sense ($\rho$). WHat type of data do you have?

Comment: Data on real estate (location, characteristics of the house, ...). Target is the selling price

Comment: If you are interested in prediction, you can use the kriging. There are a lot of libraries in R for kriging